# How do I include variables in `config.sh` into `a.sh` and `b.sh`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I've file config.sh:

```
data_dir=/home/olle/investing_data
bin_dir=/home/olle/investing_bin
```

I want to use `$data_dir` and `$bin_dir` in two separate scripts `a.sh` and `b.sh`.

How do I do it?

I tried this in a.sh and b.sh:

```
sh "config.sh"
```

But `$data_dir` and `$bin_dir` are empty.

I also tried this:

```
/bin/bash "config.sh"
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: BTW, the first answer you got from @JacobKrall would have been correct if you were starting `a.sh` and `b.sh` from `config.sh`; it's not that it was entirely/categorically wrong, but that it misunderstood how you were running your programs (as `a.sh` is actually in your use case the parent of `config.sh`, not the child, as it assumed)

Answer (score 7):

You need to [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) the file, not execute it. In `a.sh` and `b.sh`:

```
. config.sh
```

or in `bash`, the more readable alternative

```
source config.sh
```

Comment: Hi let me try immediately and I will report back my results to you here in this comment!

Comment: I'm confirming that both `.` and `source` solutions work.